# MonoTorrent track download progress of the found files

Tags: c#, .net, monotorrent

I am writing a c# application that downloads files from Magnetlink. For that I am using MonoTorrent version: **3.0.0-beta.rev0000**. I am trying to track the download progress from each file. I could not figure out if possible.

**This what i have tried:**

```
        var engine = new ClientEngine();
        engine.CriticalException += EngineCriticalException;
        engine.StatsUpdate += EngineStatsUpdate;
        var torrentManager = await engine.AddAsync(torrentLink, downloadDirectory);
        await torrentManager.StartAsync();
```

I only get DataBytesDownloaded from engine.Monitor.

Any Idea on how to track the progress of each file separatly.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is in list of files contained in ClientEngine.

Files => BitField => PercentCompelete